# Putting labels inside of a vb.net Array

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So i've created 5 different arrays for labels These are

Dim ovsoLabels As Label(), customerLabels() As Label, itemNameLabels() As Label, quantityLabels() As Label, topRightItemNameLbls(5) As Label
    Dim indexLabels() As Label

After that I have a function that assigns those variables to actual labels.

```
'assign labels to array
    ovsoLabels(0) = oVSO10
    ovsoLabels(1) = oVSO11
    ovsoLabels(2) = oVSO12
    ovsoLabels(3) = oVSO13
    ovsoLabels(4) = oVSO14
    customerLabels(0) = custLbl20
    customerLabels(1) = custLbl21
    customerLabels(2) = custLbl22
    customerLabels(3) = custLbl23
    customerLabels(4) = custLbl24
    itemNameLabels(0) = nameLbl1
    itemNameLabels(1) = nameLbl2
    itemNameLabels(2) = nameLbl3
    itemNameLabels(3) = nameLbl4
    itemNameLabels(4) = nameLbl5
    quantityLabels(0) = quantLbl1
    quantityLabels(1) = quantLbl2
    quantityLabels(2) = quantLbl3
    quantityLabels(3) = quantLbl4
    quantityLabels(4) = quantLbl6
    indexLabels(0) = indexLbl10
    indexLabels(1) = indexLbl11
    indexLabels(2) = indexLbl12
    indexLabels(3) = indexLbl13
    indexLabels(4) = indexLbl14
```

After that I call the function in my timer tick

and this is what i'm triying to do (Not quoteArray has numbers in it 0 - infinity)

```
 For i = 0 To 4
                If quantityArray(i) = Nothing Then
                ElseIf quantityArray(i) = 0 Then
                    quantityLabels(i).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
                    customerLabels(i).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
                    itemNameLabels(i).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
                    ovsoLabels(i).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
                    indexLabels(i).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
                Else
                    quantityLabels(i).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
                    customerLabels(i).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
                    itemNameLabels(i).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
                    ovsoLabels(i).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
                    indexLabels(i).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
                End If
            Next
```

This is my first post, so tell me if I can format better. The error I'm getting is that it tells me that there is no object and I need to use the keyword new. Not sure what that means, thanks!

Comment: Indicating which line gives the error, and the actual error message, will help others answer your question, although in this case we can probably guess.

Comment: Where do you declare `QuantityArray`?  What type is it? If it is `Nothing`, you have to declare it as a new object before you can use.  You might want to consider the not equals(`<>`) operator as well.

Comment: Quantity array is a string and it holds values from my database.here is the code
 For x = 0 To DT2.Rows.Count - 1
                                dataArray3(4, x) = DT2.Rows(x).Item("Qty")

(There is more but it can't fit) (For other vairables) @tinstaafl
                quantityArray2(x) = dataArray3(4, x)
            Next

Comment: My apologies, it's an int

Comment: Just so you guys know, it says "OBject reference not set to an instance of an object." At the else part when trying to change the forecolor

Comment: Are you sure that "assign labels to array" code is being executed before your loop? I'm wondering about "After that I call the function in my timer tick".  Maybe update to show where the relevant code is located.  Also, this is tagged asp.net - is that correct?

Comment: Yes, Tagged ASP.net and it is all in a function called assignArrayToLabel() and this is called at the beggining of the timertick function